# Is there a good way to keep track of large numbers of symbols in scipy?

Tags: python, sympy

I need to do symbolic manipulations to very large systems of equations, and end up with well over 200 variables that I need to do computations with. The problem is, one would usually name their variables `x`, `y`, possibly `z` when solving small system of equations. Even starting at `a`, `b`, ... you only get 26 unique variables this way.

Is there a nice way of fixing this problem? Say for instance I wanted to fill up a 14x14 matrix with a different variable in each spot. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I removed the `numpy` tag because this is a `sympy` issue.  You've gotten too many `numpy` or `list` answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use symbolic matrices via [`MatrixSymbol`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html#sympy.matrices.expressions.MatrixSymbol)

```
>>> A = MatrixSymbol('A', 14, 14)
```

This can be accessed as you would expect

```
>>> A[2, 3]
A[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightfoward way to do this is to use `sympy.symarray`, like so:

`x = sympy.symarray("x",(5,5,5))`

This creates an accordingly sized (`numpy`) array - here the size is `5x5x5` - that contains sympy variables, more specifically these variables are prefixed with whatever you chose - here `"x"`- and have as many indices as you provided dimensions, here 3. Of course you can make as many of these arrays as you need - perhaps it makes sense to use different prefixes for different groups of variables for readability etc.

You can then use these in your code by using e.g. x[i,j,k]:

`In [6]: x[0,1,4]
Out[6]: x_0_1_4`

(note that you can *not* access the elements via `x_i_j_k` - I found this a bit counterintuitive when I started using sympy, but once you get the hang on python vs. sympy variables, it makes perfect sense.)

You can of course also use slicing on the array, e.g. x[:,0,0].
If you need a python list of your variables, you can use e.g. `x.flatten().tolist()`.

This is in my opinion preferable to using `sympy.MatrixSymbol` because (a) you get to decide the number of indices you want, and (b) the elements are "normal" `sympy.Symbol`s, meaning you can be sure you can do anything with them you could also do with them if you declared them as regular symbols.
(I'm not sure this is still the case in sympy 1.1, but in sympy 1.0 it used to be that not all functionality was implemented for `MatrixElement`.)

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend the package `numpy` so you can use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays.

```
# import statement
import numpy as np

# instantiate a NumPy array (matrix) with 14 rows and 14 columns
variableMatrix = np.zeros((14,14))
```

Note ```np.zeros((14,14))`` will fill the matrix with 0s, and you can replace each element with your desired variable value later. Notice that the extra pair of parentheses in the function call is necessary!

You can access the `i,j`th element of the matrix using the syntax `variableMatrix[i-1,j-1]`. I subtracted one from the index since Python indexing starts at 0 of course.